# Oracle split by regex and aggregate again

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a `table` from where I need to get only **some part of record** `with comma` after one part of record.

`for example` I have

```
ABCD [1000-1987] BCD[101928-876] adgs[10987-786]
```

I want to get the `record` like :

```
1000-1987,101928-876,10987-786
```

Can you please help me out to get the record as mentioned.

Comment: What did you try? Did you search regexp, substr in this forum??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't use 11g and do not want to use `wm_concat`:

```sql
WITH
  my_data AS (
    SELECT 'ABCD [1000-1987] BCD[101928-876] adgs[10987-786]' AS val FROM dual
)
SELECT
    ltrim(
      MAX(
        sys_connect_by_path(
          rtrim(ltrim(regexp_substr(val, '\[[0-9-]*\]', 1, level, NULL), '['), ']'),
          ',')
      ),
    ',') AS val_part
  FROM my_data
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(val, '\[[0-9-]*\]', 1, level, NULL) IS NOT NULL
;
```

If using `wm_concat` is ok for you:

```sql
WITH
  my_data AS (
    SELECT 'ABCD [1000-1987] BCD[101928-876] adgs[10987-786]' AS val FROM dual
)
SELECT
    wm_concat(rtrim(ltrim(regexp_substr(val, '\[[0-9-]*\]', 1, level, NULL), '['), ']')) AS val_part
  FROM my_data
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(val, '\[[0-9-]*\]', 1, level, NULL) IS NOT NULL
;
```

If you use 11g:

```sql
WITH
  my_data AS (
    SELECT 'ABCD [1000-1987] BCD[101928-876] adgs[10987-786]' AS val FROM dual
)
SELECT
    listagg(regexp_substr(val, '[a-b ]*\[([0-9-]*)\] ?', 1, level, 'i', 1), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) AS val_part
  FROM my_data
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(val, '[a-b ]*\[([0-9-]*)\] ?', 1, level, 'i', 1) IS NOT NULL
;
```

Read more about string aggregation techniques: [Tim Hall about aggregation techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php)

Read more about `regexp_substr`: [regexp_substr - Oracle Documentation - 10g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm)

Read more about `regexp_substr`: [regexp_substr - Oracle Documentation - 11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to split and then aggregate it. You can use regexp_replace to keep only those characters within square brackets, then replace the square brackets by comma.

```
WITH my_data
     AS (SELECT 'ABCD [1000-1987] BCD[101928-876] adgs[10987-786]' AS val
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT RTRIM (
          REPLACE (
              REGEXP_REPLACE (val, '(\[)(.*?\])|(.)', '\2'),
                  ']', ','),
          ',')
  FROM my_data;
```